# How to make a print statement to blink only once in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to blink my print statement only once.

So now I have:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint
blue = colored(', IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII', 'blue', attrs=['blink'], )
print(blue)
```

It keeps blinking , but I want it only once.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's your terminal that makes text with certain attribute blink. You cannot control it. If you want to blink once, draw a text, wait, draw the text over the same position differently.